# How can I pass the mySQL Result in Class to an external function?

Tags: php, mysql, medoo

I use a framework for MySQL queries. In the framework, I would like to call a separate function for tracking and logging. How can I pass the result array of MySQL Query to this function?

```
/* MySQL class: */
public function query($query, $map = [], $cleanQuery = '')  {           
    $raw = $this->raw($query, $map);
    $query = $this->buildRaw($raw, $map);
    return $this->exec($query, $map, $cleanQuery);
}

public function exec($query, $map = [], $cleanQuery = '')   {
    $this->logs = [[$query, $map]];     
    $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query);

    if ($statement)     {
        foreach ($map as $key => $value)    {
            $statement->bindValue($key, $value[ 0 ], $value[ 1 ]);
        }

        $statement->execute();
        $affectedRows = $statement->rowCount();
        $errorinfos = $statement->errorInfo();

        my_own_tracking_function(.....???HOW CAN I PASS THE RESULT FROM MYSQL QUERY TO THESE FUNCTION????....);

        $this->statement = $statement;
        return $statement;
    }       
    return false;
}

/* Regular MySQL query in my code: */
$regular_result = $db->query($query)->fetchAll();

/* my own tracking function */
function my_own_tracking_function(...) { ... }
```

Comment: What framework are you using?
`$statement->execute();` seems to execute your code and since it's return is not stored in your exec method, i guess the result is stored in the `$statement` variable? How do you access your results anywhere else in your code?

Comment: It is medoo. When I pass $ statement in my function, I have only an object, no result-array. How can I get the result array from this? When I pass "$statement-> fetchAll()" to my function, I have the result array, but the original query does not work anymore.

Comment: The query does not work or your result display/processing does not work?
The problem might be that `fetchAll()` fetches all results once. MySQL works like that. Called a second time, it does not re-return the results. Probably the answer given by George Dryser will lead to your desired solution.

Comment: The query ist ok. Only the logging of the result does not work. I think, the problem is, that a cannot call fetchAll call a second time. How I have to modify the calls in the class, that a can tap the result as array?

Answer (score 0):

In our DB layer we use __destruct to close all connections and write log file like so:

```
public function __destruct() {
    // in debug mode write log file
    if (self::$DebugMode) self::_write_log_file();
    // close all active connections
    foreach (self::$CONNECTIONS as $connection) {
        if (is_object($connection)) {
            $connection->close();
        }
    }
}
```

or using custom parameter

```
    //add to top of your class
public $DataTracking = [];
```

in your method update the parameter

```
public function exec($query, $map = [], $cleanQuery = '')   {
$this->logs = [[$query, $map]];     
$statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query);

if ($statement)     {
    foreach ($map as $key => $value)    {
        $statement->bindValue($key, $value[ 0 ], $value[ 1 ]);
    }

    $statement->execute();
    $affectedRows = $statement->rowCount();
    $errorinfos = $statement->errorInfo();

    $this->DataTracking[] = 'Anything you need to log';

    $this->statement = $statement;
    return $statement;
}       
return false;
```

}

and pass it to your function like so - outside the class

```
$regular_result = $db->query($query)->fetchAll();   
my_own_tracking_function($db->DataTracking);
```

Comment: Yes, that's certainly the more elegant code. But I have now built the function my_own_tracking_function () and would like to get this working. How can I pass the result array to this function without changing the object?

Comment: Simply add Tracking data property to your db class
public $DataTracking;
and update it on query

Comment: I think that would be fine. But how I have to do this? Im a beginner and the object-oriented programming is very confusing for me. Can you please add it to my example? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I updated my answer if I understood your question correctly

Comment: But now I still have the initial problem: How I can pass the result-array to my tracking-function?

Comment: this is what passing the result to function looks like my_own_tracking_function($db->DataTracking);

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get it. If I run your example, I get only "Anything you need to log". What I have to do, to get the result-array of my MySQL-Query in my log-function? And I need the tracking from INSIDE the class. Otherwise I have to rebuild all functions in my code. Maybe it is a simple thing, but as I said, the syntax of OOP does not mean much to me.